# Weird behaviour CSS 3D transformation on Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I am writing a simple jQuery page with two images shown. Clicking on one of them triggers a CSS3 transformation, which should end zooming on the image.

The page has to be viewed on iPad, thus I must use CSS3 3D Transformation in order to use the hardware acceleration and keep the transition smooth.

I wrote a simple demo script here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrearota/KAdmV/4/

E.g. here is how I zoom in, using scale factor. Please note that I use the z property trying to get the div over the closed one:

```
Carousel.prototype.openLeft = function (callback) {
    var that = this;
    if (this.leftStatus != 'open') {
      this.left.transition({
          z: '+=100',
          scale: 2 
        }, function () {
          that.leftStatus = 'open';
          if (callback) callback();
        });
    } else {
        if (callback) callback();
    }
};
```

As you can see, if you clic on the left image, the image is zoomed in and goes over the right one. When you click on the right one, vice versa. But then, if you click again on the left one, you can see an issue on image stacking as the left zoomed image goes under the minimized right one.

Any hint?

Comment: Please write reasons of downvoting please, so I can correct the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can remove the transform on the second image and it will go back behind the first one.  So in other words, on image click I would probably first remove all occurrences of  the transform property before applying to the clicked image.

Or you could also set both images to position:relative and then on click set the z-index to something like 5 and set all other images to something below it such as 3.  But again, you'll need to clear these inline styles so that when another image is clicked there are remnants from before that give you un-clear results.

Comment: The first method worked. I let jQuery Transit to manage the transition, so I had to remove the CSS transformation attribute manually, according to your suggestion.

I uploaded the working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrearota/J87GS/